# Why do you have to leak dependency of super type in Android studio 3.0+?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project with 2 modules: `MyApp` and `MyLibrary`. `Mylibrary` project has a `MyCardView` class that extends `CardView` class from `com.android.support:cardview-v7` dependency which is included in `MyLibrary`'s `build.gradle` via `implementation`  since I don't want to leak `CardView` library to modules using MyLibrary: in this case, it is `MyApp` module. But then when I build and run `MyApp` module I get following error:

> e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class com.my.library.MyCardView, unresolved supertypes: android.support.v7.widget.CardView

To resolve this issue I have to either include `CardView` dependency via `api` in `MyLibrary`'s `build.gradle` - but then I leak this `CardView` dependency to all modules using `MyLibrary`, or explicitly include `CardView` dependency in `MyApp`'s `build.gradle`.

So my question is: Is there a way to use this `CardView` dependency in `MyLibrary` but without leaking it or needing to explicitly include it in every module using `MyLibrary` dependency? If not - why does `MyLibrary` has to leak it's `CardView` dependency?

P.S: Both modules are written in Kotlin, but I don't suppose it has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: How is your 'MyLibrary' included in 'MyApp', can you show the gradle dependency?

Comment: @dumazy, I include it like `implementation project(':MyLibrary')`. But whether I include `MyLibrary` in `MyApp` via `implementation` or `api` - it shows the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a tooling problem: having a superclass is not an implementation detail, it's an essential part of a class.

You could not use `MyCardView` without knowing about `CardView` as well. For example, how would you expect the methods it inherits from the superclass to be visible and executable?

This is why you need to have `CardView` available wherever you want to use `MyCardView`.